# ListBox multiple Selection get all selected values

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable, listbox

I'm having a problem since a while now an just can't find any solution that works for me. I have a `ListBox` which is filled up with a `DataTable` like

```
listbox.DataSource = table;  
listbox.Displaymember = "Name";    
listbox.ValueMember = "ID";
```

If I now select an item in my listbox I can get it out like:

```
listbox.SelectedValue.toString();
```

My Problem:

What can I do if I would like to have ALL selected Values from a `ListBox` where multiple selection is enabled and save them all in an array or something like that?!

I can't use `SelectedItems` cause that is not giving me the information I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var lst = listBox1.SelectedItems.Cast<DataRowView>();
foreach (var item in lst)
{
     MessageBox.Show(item.Row[0].ToString());// Or Row[1]...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Or if you want only iterate over the selected items you can use `SelectedIndices` property:

```
foreach (int i in listbox.SelectedIndices)
{
    // listbox.Items[i].ToString() ...
}
```

Or:

```
foreach (var item in listbox.SelectedItems)
{
    MessageBox.Show(item.ToString());
}
```

Comment: For your first option it tells me for .Selected
'object' does not contain a definition for 'selected'

Second option it tells me somethin similar under .GetSelectedIndices()